# Is there any standard method to lockout the user for certain time in salesforce sites

Tags: force.com-sites

I went through the sites class and I did not find any standard method to Lockout User. Does any one know have come across this please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be managed using the Profiles. In Profiles we can define the policies of the password. Only thing I need to do is when the user is logging in I need to query from my public site and show him the message.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following link(May help).
http://simplysfdc.blogspot.com/2013/05/disable-user-login-to-salesforce.html